# How does $\zeta=A\cos(\omega\cdot t-kx)$ satisfy this equation:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wave-equation

How does $\zeta=A\cos(\omega\cdot t-kx)$ satisfy this equation:

$$\frac{\partial^2\zeta}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2\zeta}{\partial t ^2}$$

Comment: What is the connection between $c, k$ and $\omega$?

Comment: @Chinny84 This is actually in my physics book and I have not done any partial differential equations in my math course. Thats why I am having difficulties understanding whats going on.

Comment: @Chinny84 I really wish we had something like multivariable calculus in our first semester. Unfortunately pde's are taught next semester. German universities...

Comment: @rzeta some of the best physicist I have studied/researched with have been German and or studied at a German university. so I would say you are in a fine place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, it doesn't obviously. However, if there is a relationship between $\omega$ and $k$, then it can. Note that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \zeta}{\partial x^2} = -Ak^2\cos(\omega t - kx)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \zeta}{\partial t^2} = -A\omega^2\cos(\omega t - kx)
$$
and so the equation
$$
-Ak^2\cos(\omega t - kx) = \frac{\partial^2 \zeta}{\partial x^2} = \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \zeta}{\partial t^2} =-\frac{1}{c^2}A\omega^2\cos(\omega t - kx)
$$
is satisfied if $c^2 = \omega^2/k^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate $\zeta $ twice relative to $x$ and relative to $t$ we get

$$\frac{\partial^2\zeta}{\partial x^2}=k^2\zeta$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial^2\zeta}{\partial t^2}=\omega^2 \zeta$$
so in order to have the given equation we should have
$$\frac{\omega}{c}=k$$

Comment: You're welcome.